# Connect to Microsoft Exchange Server with Spring Integration Mail 

Tags: spring, exchange-server, spring-integration

I want to connect to Microsoft Exchange 2010 with IMAP using Spring Integration Mail.
My question is how the connection string exactly look like.

Let's say:

```
domain=earth
user=jdoe
email=jon.doe@earth.com
Folder=inbox
```

As far as I know, MS Exchange only supports imaps for connection to.

My Spring integration config looks like this:

```
<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imaps.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
</util:properties>

<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
    store-uri="imaps://earth/jdoe/jon.doe:jdoespw@example.mailhost.com/inbox" channel="recieveEmailChannel"
    should-delete-messages="false" should-mark-messages-as-read="true"
    auto-startup="true" java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5"
        time-unit="SECONDS" />
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="recieveEmailChannel" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel"
    ref="mailReceiver" method="receive" />

<bean id="mailReceiver"
    class="com.earth.MailReceiver" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it out now. It doesn't has to do something with the connection string.
For those who want to connect to Exchange, here some hints.

Here's my config:

```
<util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imaps.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.starttls.enable">true</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
</util:properties>

<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
    store-uri="imap://<username>:<password>@<exchange-url>/INBOX" channel="recieveEmailChannel"
    should-delete-messages="false" should-mark-messages-as-read="false"
    auto-startup="true" java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5"
    time-unit="SECONDS" />
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="recieveEmailChannel" />

<int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel"
    ref="reviewMailService" method="receive" />
```

Typically Exchange uses Imaps with STARTTLS connection.

To perform the SSL handshake, you can use the InstallCert Java program:
http://code.google.com/p/java-use-examples/source/browse/trunk/src/com/aw/ad/util/InstallCert.java

Answer (score 0):

1. The first node after the imaps:// needs to be the fqdn of the server, not the domain (e.g. email.earth.com).
2. There's a FAQ about exchange credentials here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html
3. IIRC, IMAP is **not** enabled by default on Exchange and the admin has to enable it.

Comment: How will be the format of the connection string after the fqdn?

Comment: Sorry; I misread your URL - I see you have user@fqdn.
That faq seems to say you need domain\user\emailid@fqdn